# how to use a variable instead of a string inside regex search function in python

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex function to extract a specific word in a string

```
fileName = re.search(r'path1\w([A-Za-z\d]+)', self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

**path1** is an actual string

What if I would like to replace it by `fileName` variable where `fileName = "path1"`

I tried:

```
print re.search(r'\w([A-Za-z\d]+)' % fileName, self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Why did I get this error ? how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `%s` in your regex :

```
print re.search(r'%s\w([A-Za-z\d]+)' % fileName, self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

Or as a more pythoinc and flexible way you can use `str.format` function :

```
print re.search(r'{}\w([A-Za-z\d]+)'.format(fileName), self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

Note that is second way if you have a list of file names you can loop over  them and pass the file names to `format`.

Answer (score 0):

One should be very careful when interpolating strings into languages like Regex. In this case, you should probably escape the string first:

```
expression = r'{}\w([A-Za-z\d]+)'.format(re.escape(fileName))
re.search(expression, self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

It's maybe also worth noting [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)'s named lists:

```
import regex

expression = regex.compile(r'\L<filename>\w([A-Za-z\d]+)', filename=[fileName])
expression.search(self.fileList[0]).group(1)
```

This avoids having to regex-escape the literal, and works better if there are multiple options. (Plus `regex` is tons better anyway, so all the more reason to use it!)